# Azure Graph API Nested Group Membership

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to query a user's nested group membership. `memberOf` only give direct group membership. When I try `getMemberGroups`, `getMemberObjects`, `checkMemberGroups`, etc. using version 1.5 or 1.6, I'm getting this:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Method Not Allowed"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be making a GET request. According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups), you need to make a POST request for getMemberGroups.

URL:

```
https://graph.windows.net/domain.com/users/first.last@domain.com/getMemberGroups?api-version=1.6
```

Request body:

```
{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

Here the parameter defines if you want only security groups back, or if it should return Office 365 groups too.